# I want to edit my sass file from Chrome dev tool from element tab, is that possible?

Tags: html, css, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

In my project I have a sass file which I set sourcemappath through the node-sass. I am using Node-sass to compile my sass file. I have map my .css file on my system. so any changes I made through source panel save my file on the disk. and it's compiled back by node-sass. I am not seeing reload my auto-generated css anywhere so I think it's on by default.

I want to save the changes that I made on element panel. When I click on css file from element panel (which is scss file, work through sourcemap) it doesn't have my changes.

Is it possible to save my changes from element panel. I made some changes and I didn't see in source panel. when I refresh I can still see my changes but it doesn't reflect in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently an experimental feature. It is hidden behind flags since it could be unstable and break things. If you'd like to try it now then do the following:

1. Go to `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments` in your omnibar
2. Enable the flag for Experimental DevTools Features
3. Restart the browser
4. Open DevTools and go to the Settings then a new `Experiments` tab on the left is available
5. In the experiments tab, turn on the `Live SASS` option
6. Restart DevTools

You should now have changes in the Elements panel persist into your Sass as long as it is properly source-mapped.

Paul Irish covered this feature (among others) in his portion of the I/O 2016 talk about [Accelerating Your Workflow](https://youtu.be/x8u0n4dT-WI?t=14m6s).

Comment: Do you know is it possible to not save changes to the source until I click save all or something like that?

Comment: No it is called "live" for a reason. Thing are immediately persisted, since that is the current state of the CSSOM in the browser.

Comment: Thx, but saving only when desired obviously makes sense. You do not want to be forced to do one thing or the other. Can be called however they want... ^^

Comment: "Thx, but saving only when desired obviously makes sense." Only in certain contexts. Chrome as a whole is built to provide the least options making for a simpler to understand experience. Having a specific save context their optionally complicates the UX and code in multiple ways. There would probably need to be an "Autosaving is *breaking* an application" in some way issue to have an option to disable that and make it manual.

Comment: I do not agree at all. It's a button that calls a function and gives you much more needed flexibility. Obviously I do not want to autosave all changes or not save all changes at all. I want to save when I like what I see and not decide right upfront. This makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, let's assume you get a magical button. Where would it go? How would it fit into the user experience of that place? Is room being taken away from an existing feature to provide it, if so is it warranted? How does the system keep a diff only of changes between the last save and the next to flush to the filesystem? Could that have a significant impact on performance in scenarios with large files or sets of changes? There are many concerns with "just adding a button". Things sound simpler than they are in reality. Like I said, if something is outright broken, then there is a case.

Comment: We do not have to agree. IMO the best workflow is clear and for sure not impossible to code/realize. Maybe there's already a tool out there that has that feature. I'll research a bit.

Comment: I never said it was impossible to understand or code. I'm saying in terms of whether it should be in DevTools directly there are numerous concerns to be dealt with for long-term maintainability of the code. There is a big difference between that and something being "impossible". Please don't assume what other people are intending with what they say, that's how things digress into being extremely unproductive. It sounds to me like *live* updating isn't what you want. Which means the Live Sass feature isn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated January 2020 - Chrome Version 79 - Mac 10.14.6

1. Goto Chrome dev toolbar
2. Setting
3. Workspace
4. Click on 'Add folder' button
5. Add your working directory path
6. Goto 'Sources' tab - you will find this in between console and network tab
7. command + P (mac) search for desired file - example - main.scss
8. make code changes and verify

I also found that you can make changes in Dev toolbar as well as in Editor, they will get synced :)

Comment: But.. can you make the changes in the Elements (Styles) tab so they are synced with the files?

Comment: @Reloecc - Nope I dont think, Please let me know if you find workaround for same :)

Comment: the feature was dropped, worked flawly years ago, but chromium team said they won't try to fix it (I have no source atm).

Comment: Thanks @Reloecc hope it will be fixed in future

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe what you want is possible. You might want to look at options like LiveReload for this behaviour. You could change the code in IDE, compile, and livereload will detect your changes to the compiled .css file on the filesystem and reload it in your browser.

Comment: Live reload work pretty well already when I change my file in source panel. The only problem is if I refresh my changes is shown in element (Chrome didn't fade them away, I think it's feature to get the css back when I accidentally refresh my page but it's cause some confusion sometime).