# Is there any way to open local file directly from 'Elements > Styles' tab in Chrome devtools?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, browser-sync

I'm using the Chrome devtools persistence feature with `browser-sync` and `sass`.

I set a `Workspace` pointing to my scss folder and I can edit scss files from Chrome and have all css files created correctly, applied to browser real-time and saved in hard drive.
However when I select an element on the `Elements > Styles` tab and make some changes, the changed file is the `http://localhost:3000...` one so changes are not kept. Then I still have to find the local file in the `Sources` tab to copy these changes.

I'm not sure if this is the best we can get but if we could either open the local file directly from the `Elements > Style` tab instead of the `http://localhost:3000...` file or somehow automatically copy any changes in the `http://localhost:3000...` file to local file the workflow would be even easier and faster.

Does any one knows how to accomplish that, even using some app/extension?

UPDATE:

From Rohit answer I found that if I turn off `css source maps` in devtools settings then it is correctly synced, showing the green circle on the `Elements > Style` and keep my changes, although it still pointing to `http://localhost:3000...style.css` file.
However then it only changes this file, not the specific `partials/*.scss` file and if I run `sass` compiler it overrides the `css` with the old code.
With the `css source maps` on Chrome finds my partial scss correctly but doesn't show the green circle so it's not synced and doesn't keep changes.

The problem seems to be with syncing `scss` files instead of `css`.

I was trying with a `Workspace` pointing to my root `scss` folder, also tried pointing it to the direct parent of the file beeing edited and still not syncing corretly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a shot in the dark but,I beleive if you add the parent folder of the files you are working on from Devtools > Sources Tab > Filesystem tab > Add folder to workspace.
Like so :
[image]

Then navigate to your folder, and add reload the page. After reloading if you see green 
like so:
[image]

It means it is synced and will update without you going to the sources tab.

Comment: if I turn off css source maps in devtools settings it get the green circle and although it still pointing to localhost:3000 the changes are kept. However then it only changes my style.css not the specific partial scss and if I run sass compiler it overrides the css with the old code.
With the source maps on Chrome finds my partial scss correctly but doesn't keep changes.

Comment: Yes, you can only change non-compiling css like css. But, as you know sass needs to be compiled before it can be used, and chrome does not provide a feature to edit a sass file and then to create the css from it and then render it as of now. So, you may have work around with css files only. This may help you though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360983/i-want-to-edit-my-sass-file-from-chrome-dev-tool-from-element-tab-is-that-possi

Comment: Yes, I know but Netbeans is automatically compiling sass on any changes in scss folder. So I just need to be able to sync the scss as I could do with css. Changing the localhost file on devtools would render right away on screen, then if files are synced the scss will change on disk and Netbeans will compile sass. I guess like this I wouldn't need browser-sync.

Comment: The question you shared seems to be about the same thing, but **Live SASS** option is not available in the experiments tab anymore. Don't know if it's stable and running or was droped.

Comment: Yes that was what I found closest to your query

Answer (score 0):

Adding the root of my project to the `Workspace` synced `scss` files correctly. Now when I click an element on the `Element > Styles` tab, `Quick source` opens the right file at the right `scss` rule but doesn't follow my changes in the `Element > Styles` tab (as it does using pure `css`) and I still need to copy changes to `Quick source` or edit there directly, save and wait `sass` compilation to apply changes on screen.

The workflow is much easier now but I'm not choosing this as the correct anwser because is not "as live as css" yet and maybe someone knows how to do this final step.

PS: `browser-sync` is not needed in this setup, just something to compile `sass` and Chrome apply changes automatically.